# scala reflection: getDeclaringTrait?

Tags: reflection, scala

When I research a new library, I sometimes find it hard to locate the implementation of a method.

In Java, Metho#getDeclaringClass provides the class that declared a given method. So by iterating over Class#getMethods, I can find for each method, the class that declared it.

In Scala, traits are converted to Java interfaces and a class that extends a trait will implement the methods of the trait by forwarding them to a companion class defining these methods statically. This means, that Method#getDeclaringClass will return the class, not the trait:

```
scala> trait A { def foo = {println("hi")}}
defined trait A

scala> class B extends A
defined class B

scala> classOf[B].getMethods.find(_.getName() == "foo").get.getDeclaringClass
res3: java.lang.Class[_] = class B
```

What is the best way to work around this? Meaning, given a class, how can I get a List[(Method, Class)] where each tuple is a method and the trait/class it was declared in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Scala 2.8 you can use the **ScalaSigParser** to parse the scala specific byte code information.

This will be more stable than the byte code serialization format of scala traits, classes and methods.

```
import tools.scalap.scalax.rules.scalasig._
import scala.runtime._

val scalaSig = ScalaSigParser.parse(classOf[RichDouble]).get
val richDoubleSymbol = scalaSig.topLevelClasses.head
val methods = richDoubleSymbol.children filter ( _ match {
    case m : MethodSymbol => true
    case _ => false
})

methods foreach println
richDoubleSymbol.isTrait
ScalaSigParser.parse(classOf[Ordered[Any]]).get.topLevelClasses.head.isTrait
```

Prints:

```
scala> methods foreach println
MethodSymbol(x, owner=0, flags=20080004, info=23 ,None)
MethodSymbol(<init>, owner=0, flags=200, info=33 ,None)
[...]
MethodSymbol(isPosInfinity, owner=0, flags=200, info=117 ,None)
MethodSymbol(isNegInfinity, owner=0, flags=200, info=117 ,None)

scala> richDoubleSymbol.isTrait
res1: Boolean = false

scala> ScalaSigParser.parse(classOf[Ordered[Any]]).get.topLevelClasses.head.isTrait
res2: Boolean = true
```

I suppose following this road you can build a reflection API for Scala.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that sort-of-works:

```
def methods(c: Class[_]): Array[String] = {
    val dm = try {
        val cls = if (c.isInterface) Class.forName(c.getName() + "$class") else c

        cls.getDeclaredMethods().map(m =>                            
            decode(c.getCanonicalName) + "#" + 
            decode(m.getName) + "(" + 
            {m.getParameterTypes.toList match {
                case h :: tail => tail.map{(c: Class[_]) => decode(c.getCanonicalName)}.mkString(",")
                case Nil => ""
            }} + "): " +    
            decode(m.getReturnType.getCanonicalName))
    } catch {case _ => Array[String]()}

    dm ++ c.getInterfaces.flatMap(methods(_))
}
```

---

```
scala> trait A {def hi = {println("hi")}}
scala> class B extends A
scala> methods(classOf[B]).foreach(println(_))
Main.$anon$1.B#$tag(): int
Main.$anon$1.B#Main$$anon$A$$$outer(): Main.$anon$1
Main.$anon$1.B#Main$$anon$B$$$outer(): Main.$anon$1
Main.$anon$1.B#hi(): void
Main.$anon$1.A#$init$(): void
Main.$anon$1.A#hi(): void
scala.ScalaObject#$tag(): int
scala.ScalaObject#$init$(): void
```

You can see there's some filtering that can be done and maybe some conversions. 
The most annoying thing is that B has a declaration of 'hi', because it forwards the call to A$class#hi. However, this is indistinguishable from the case where B actually overrides 'hi' with its own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is actually "research[ing] a new library," the documentation gives you this information. Inherited methods (not overridden) are listed and linked (their names only) under the inherited class that defines them.

Is this not sufficient for the purposes of understanding the libary? Also, each documentation page includes a link to the source code.

Comment: you're assuming that every library is well documented. and besides, my question is about reflection in general, not "how can I research new libraries". that part was so that people won't start asking "why do you need such reflection for?".

Comment: Ascertaining the things you ask about (and you did say in your very first sentence that you were doing research into new libraries) are available reliably and completely in the source code and hence in the Scaladoc HTML. Furthermore, given the nature of the relationship between Scala and the JVM, more information will always be available via the source than via the bytecode.