# Is there in scala the equivalent of the c# nameof?

Tags: c#, scala

In c# I can write code such as this (I ran it Linqpad 5):

```
void Main()
{
    new Test { Property1 = 100 }.Dump();
    Console.WriteLine(nameof(Test.Property1));
}

class Test
{
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
    override public String ToString()
    {
        return $"{nameof(Property1)}={Property1}";
    }
}
```

Is there a scala equivalent of nameof?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe what you want is this! Hope this can help you. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105002/is-it-possible-to-recover-the-name-of-the-function-from-within-the-function-in-s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105002/is-it-possible-to-recover-the-name-of-the-function-from-within-the-function-in-s)

Comment: "Property1" would work.

Comment: what is scala ?

Comment: @pedrofurla The benefit of `nameof` is that it is turned into a string at compile time but it otherwise still a symbol reference so can be reliably refactored with the source property.

Comment: @LeiYang A functional programming language for the JVM. http://scala-lang.org

Comment: @Frank: My goal is to avoid using magic strings. nameof in C# probably has support from the compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Scala it can be done by a (macro) library instead of needing special language-level support. There is one at https://github.com/dwickern/scala-nameof.

Answer (score 3):

There is no any similar methods in scala as of C#, If you really want the function than you can use [scala-reflection](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.0/scala-reflect/#package).