# Extract Scala function name and params implicitly

Tags: scala, playframework

I have the following code:

```
def disableRules(someId: String) = Action.async { implicit req =>
   Metrics.measureTime("disableRules") {
     someFutureOpr(someId).map(_ => Ok)
     .recover {
       case e: Exception => handlerError(s"Failure occurred on disableRules request ${e.getMessage}", "disableRules")
     }
   }
 }

def activeRules(someId: String) = Action.async { implicit req =>
  Metrics.measureTime("activeRules") {
    someFutureOpr2(someId).map(_ => Ok)
    .recover {
      case e: Exception => handlerError(s"Failure occurred on activeRules request ${e.getMessage}", "activeRules")
    }
  }
}
...
```

As you can see, I have `mesureTime` and `handleError` functions that I pass to them the **name** of the function as String, is there way to make it implicitly, I mean its will take the function Name, if not - there way to extract the function Name and print it, also regarding params.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to recover the name of the function from within the function in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105002/is-it-possible-to-recover-the-name-of-the-function-from-within-the-function-in-s)

Comment: Its not cover s it all, is there a way to make `messureTime` and `handleError` get this value implicitly? (Also if there some way of taking the parms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this with a macro (and no runtime reflection):

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

class CaptureImpl(val c: blackbox.Context) {
  import c.universe._

  def describe[T: c.WeakTypeTag](
      expr: c.Expr[T]
  ): c.Expr[String] = c.Expr[String](q"(${expr.tree.toString()})")
}

object CaptureMethod {
  def apply[T](expr: T): String = macro CaptureImpl.describe[T]
}
```

Example:

```
object Test {
  def foo(): String = "hello"
  def bar(a: Int): Int = a
  def baz(s: String): String = s
  
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(CaptureMethod(foo()))
    println(CaptureMethod(bar(1)))
    println(CaptureMethod(baz("yes")))
  }
}
```

Yields:

```
Test.this.foo()
Test.this.bar(1)
Test.this.baz("yes")
```

Comment: Nice!
How can I send CaptureMethod implicitly from the recover? (In my code on the question)

Comment: @ZviMints What would you like to do inside recover exactly?

Comment: I would like to call `handleError` (with or without additional fields [In that case, handle implicitly]) which can print the caller function (in this example - `disableRules(someId)` or `activeRules(someId)`

Comment: @ZviMints I see, well that would be a bit more tricky as we need to pass in the calling function ATM, I'm not sure if a macro can implicitly infer the context it's in.

Comment: Is there maybe some other way to get the data on compile time?

Answer (score 2):

Calculate it inside `Metrics`:

```
object Metrics {
  def currentMethodName() : String = Thread.currentThread.getStackTrace()(3).getMethodName

  def measureTime(): Unit = {
    println(currentMethodName)
  }
}
```

Then for example:

```
def a1() = {
  Metrics.measureTime()
}

def a2() = {
  Metrics.measureTime()
}
```

will output:

```
a1
a2
```

### Is this a safe operation?

If we had:

```
def currentMethodName() : String = Thread.currentThread.getStackTrace.toList.mkString("\n")
```

we get:

```
java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1559)
HelloWorld1$Metrics$.currentMethodName(HelloWorld1.scala:69)
HelloWorld1$Metrics$.measureTime(HelloWorld1.scala:72)
HelloWorld1$.a1(HelloWorld1.scala:77)
HelloWorld1$.main(HelloWorld1.scala:103)
HelloWorld1.main(HelloWorld1.scala)
```

So we see that:

- In index 0 we get `getStackTrace`.
- In index 1 we have `currentMethodName`.
- In index 2 we have `measureTime`.

Since `measureTime` is not the first method of the stack trace, fir sure we have another element in the stack trace. Therefore in your case yes, it is safe.

Comment: I could not find the relevant stack trace since its came from the recover method

Comment: @ZviMints It's ok to use the other solution. It is a good solution. The reason you got that behaviour is that you called `currentMethodName` inside the `recover` section. You should have called it before `Metrics.measureTime`.

Comment: Exectually, but then i can just print the name of the function, I want to hand it implicitly on the `recover`, the `messureTime` is less important for me.