# Accessing java.awt.Container.getComponents from scala

Tags: swing, unit-testing, scala

I'm trying to write automated tests for a gui application written in scala with swing. I'm adapting the code from [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-11-2004/jw-1115-swing.html?page=2) which leverages [getName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getName%28%29) to find the right ui element in the tree.

This is a self-contained version of my code. It's incomplete, untested, and probably broken and/or non-idiomatic and/or suboptimal in various ways, but my question is regarding the compiler error listed below.

```
import scala.swing._
import java.awt._
import ListView._

import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.scalatest.FunSpec
import org.scalatest.matchers.ShouldMatchers

object MyGui extends SimpleSwingApplication {
  def top = new MainFrame {
    title = "MyGui"

    val t = new Table(3, 3)
    t.peer.setName("my-table")
    contents = t
  }
}

object TestUtils {
  def getChildNamed(parent: UIElement, name: String): UIElement = {
    // Debug line
    println("Class: " + parent.peer.getClass() +
            " Name: " + parent.peer.getName())

    if (name == parent.peer.getName()) { return parent }

    if (parent.peer.isInstanceOf[java.awt.Container]) {

      val children = parent.peer.getComponents()
      /// COMPILER ERROR HERE   ^^^

      for (child <- children) {
        val matching_child = getChildNamed(child, name)
        if (matching_child != null) { return matching_child }
      }
    }

    return null
  }
}

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class MyGuiSpec extends FunSpec {
  describe("My gui window") {
    it("should have a table") {
      TestUtils.getChildNamed(MyGui.top, "my-table")
    }
  }
}
```

When I compile this file I get:

```
29: error: value getComponents is not a member of java.awt.Component
      val children = parent.peer.getComponents()
                                 ^
one error found
```

[As far as I can tell](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponents%28%29), getComponents is in fact a member of java.awt.Component. I used [the code in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1976362/67022) to dump the methods on `parent.peer`, and I can see that getComponents is in the list.

Answers that provide another approach to the problem (automated gui testing in a similar manner) are welcome, but I'd really like to understand why I can't access getComponents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're looking at two different classes. Your javadoc link points to `java.awt.Container`, which indeed has `getComponents` method. On the other hand, the compiler is looking for `getComponents` on `java.awt.Component` (the parent class), which is returned by `parent.peer`, and can't find it.

Instead of `if (parent.peer.isInstanceOf[java.awt.Container]) ...`, you can verify the type of parent.peer and cast it like this:

```
parent.peer match {
      case container: java.awt.Container =>
         // the following works because container isA Container
         val children = container.getComponents
        // ...
      case _ => // ...
}
```

Comment: Argh, I must have looked at that 20 times and didn't see that it was a different class. Thanks.