# What reflection capabilities can we expect from Scala 2.10?

Tags: scala, reflection

Scala 2.10 brings reflection other than that provided the JVM (or I guess CLR).

What in particular do we have to look forward to, and how will it improve on the platform?

For example, will there be a class that reflects the language's convertibility between fields and accessor methods, so that I can iterate over the properties of an object?

Comment: Hey, I really want examples - there's a bounty now!

Comment: Well, still no real examples, and this question is now Google's top hit for `Scala reflection 2.10` Ho hum, @VonC has it I think, but if anyone can show me user-level code I'd still be grateful.

Comment: Duncan, thank you! See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708485/scala-class-getfields/7710418#7710418 Turns out with current 2.10.0-SNAPSHOT you already can iterate over properties of a class.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**update 2012-07-04**:

[Daniel SOBRAL](https://plus.google.com/109369058791340660984) (also [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53013/daniel-c-sobral)) details in his blog post "[JSON serialization with reflection in Scala! Part 1 - So you want to do reflection?](http://dcsobral.blogspot.fr/2012/07/json-serialization-with-reflection-in.html)" some of the features coming with reflection:

> To recapitulate, Scala 2.10 will come with a Scala reflection library.
>   That library is used by the compiler itself, but **divided into layers through [the cake pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172188/understanding-scalas-cake-pattern), so different users see different levels of detail**, keeping jar sizes adequate to each one's use, and hopefully hiding unwanted detail.
>
> The reflection library also **integrates with the upcoming macro facilities, enabling enterprising coders to manipulate code at compile time**.

---

**update 2012-06-14.** (from [Eugene Burmako](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131615/eugene-burmako)):
In **[Scala 2.10.0-M4](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/12702)**, we have released the new **reflection API** that will most likely make it into 2.10.0-final without significant changes.
More details about the API can be found:

- SO answer [Get companion object instance with new Scala reflection API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020746/get-companion-object-instance-with-new-scala-reflection-api/11031443#11031443)
- [Scala Reflection SIP, June 2012](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Z1VhhNPplbUpaZPIYdc0_EUv5RiGQ2X4oqp0i-vz1qw/edit?pli=1) by Martin Odersky ([SIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIP), actually "[Scala Improvement Process](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/index.html)")
- [summary and migration route from M3](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/6bb5975289c5b11cb8c88dd4629286956b5d3d27)

Extracts:

> Universes and mirrors are now separate entities:
>
> - universes host reflection artifacts (trees, symbols, types, etc),
> - mirrors abstract loading of those artifacts (e.g. `JavaMirror` loads stuff
>     using a classloader and annotation unpickler, while GlobalMirror uses internal compiler `classreader` to achieve the same goal).
>
> Public reflection API is split into **`scala.reflect.base`** and `scala.reflect.api`.
>
> - The former represents a minimalistic snapshot that is exactly enough to
>     build reified trees and types.
> - To build, but not to analyze - everything smart (for example, getting a type signature) is implemented in `scala.reflect.api`.
>
> Both reflection domains have their own universe: `scala.reflect.basis` and
>   `scala.reflect.runtime.universe`.
>
> - The former is super lightweight and doesn't involve any classloaders,
> - while the latter represents a stripped down compiler.

---

Initial answer, Sept. 2011:

You can see evolutions of the reflect package in the [Scala GitHub repo](https://github.com/scala/scala), with this two very recent commits:

- [Changes to Liftcode to use new reflection semantics, where a compiler uses type checking](https://github.com/scala/legacy-svn-scala/commit/ed89775a0551b4c4c29ac56490ce6f84e7954ea6).
- [Started work on compiler toolbox that can compile reflect trees at runtime](https://github.com/scala/legacy-svn-scala/commit/719ba9939a3843ea75cefee1f5d6ba1e22fce373).

(Liftcode being, according to [this thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala.internals/2517),  aims at simplifying "writing code that writes code")

The class [`scala/reflect/internal/Importers.scala`](https://codereview.scala-lang.org/fisheye/browse/scala-svn/scala/trunk/src/compiler/scala/reflect/internal/Importers.scala?hb=true) (created yesterday!) is a good example of using those latest reflection feature.

Comment: Both links to github commits are no longer exists.

Comment: @om-nom-nom: links restored. They are now available in the [legacy-svn-scala](https://github.com/scala/legacy-svn-scala) repo.

Comment: @Eugene: thank you for the edit. I took the liberty of adding a few links and references.

Comment: SIP = Scala Improvement Process

Comment: @Antoras: darn, that one wasn't in the Wikipedia disambiguation page! Answer edited.

Answer (score 11):

Two links which should be of interest:

- The scala-internals [mailing list discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/scala-internals/sYxdXQo5g18/discussion) on the reflection api.
- The nightly build [api doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.reflect.api.package) for 2.10-SNAPSHOT.

Personally I am hoping to use this for doing runtime discovery of extensions (i.e. a type that extends a known trait), and generating UI forms and a few other things from those.

Comment: Thanks, the mailing list leads to the wiki - https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SIW/Reflection

Comment: and quite frankly it's all completely opaque to me!

Answer (score 5):

With current 2.10M4 you already can iterate over members of a class:

```
reflect.runtime.universe.typeOf[MyClass].members.filter(!_.isMethod)
```

The above code lists `Symbol` objects representing members of a class `MyClass` which are not methods. There are tons of ways you can fine-tune this.