# Scala Class.getFields

Tags: scala, reflection

For purposes of my app I need to be able to find out a list of fields of a **type** (not an instance) and types of those fields in runtime. So far I was only able to get a list of methods of a case class containing getters with `classOf[MyCaseClass].getMethods` and nothing useful from a simple class. Am I missing something? Are there any reflection libraries for that kinda purposes? How's that done correctly?

Comment: I'm confused - the title says fields, and then you go looking for methods. Which do you want?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/7477248/97777

Comment: Thanks Duncan, I'll look into it. I went looking for methods to find properties which have names and types corresponding to their fields.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using Scala 2.10 reflection:

```
scala> import reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}
import reflect.runtime.{universe=>ru}
scala> trait A { val field1: Int; val field2: Char; def meth1: Int }
defined trait A
scala> val fieldSymbols = ru.typeOf[A].members.collect{ case m: ru.MethodSymbol if m.isGetter => m }
fieldSymbols: Iterable[reflect.runtime.universe.MethodSymbol] = List(value field2, value field1)
```

The returned symbols contain all the type information, e.g.:

```
scala> fieldSymbols.map(_.typeSignature)
res16: Iterable[reflect.runtime.universe.Type] = List(=> scala.Char, => scala.Int)
```

Comment: Good stuff - you might want to add an answer there!

Comment: Posted! Mission accomplished, now I can go to sleep.

Comment: `collect{ case m: ru.MethodSymbol if m.isGetter => m }` gives the warning "abstract type pattern ru.MethodSymbol is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure" for the `MethodSymbol`. Not sure so far how to eliminate it.

Comment: I'm a Scala neophyte, but I resolved the warning by doing `collect{ case m if ru.MethodSymbolTag.runtimeClass.isInstance(m) && m.asInstanceOf[ru.MethodSymbol].isGetter => m }`

Answer (score 6):

You may want to take a look at this [document on reflecting scala](http://lamp.epfl.ch/teaching/projects/archive/coppel_report.pdf).  `getMethods` is a method from Java reflection.  What can't you find there?  From the [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html):

- String getName(): Returns the name of the method represented by this Method object, as a String.
- Class[] getParameterTypes(): Returns an array of Class objects that represent the formal parameter types, in declaration order, of the method represented by this Method object.
- Class getReturnType(): Returns a Class object that represents the formal return type of the method represented by this Method object.

You could read more about [Java reflection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html).

Note that not all type information will be available at runtime because of [erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Comment: Thanks I know about that project and have actually already downloaded their lib, but I can't get it to compile since it has too many conflicts with 2.9.1 which I am using. You don't need to explain Java reflection to me. What I was looking for were clean ways of dealing with it in Scala. The problems I have with reflection is that Scala fields are not presented there at all and `getMethods` returns a bunch of generated methods which need to be filtered out and I was hoping that there existed a consistent algorithm for that. Guess I'll have to analyze the *Mirrors* code.

Comment: Looks like your question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204057/reflection-api-for-scala then.

Comment: The link is dead, an updated link would be appreciated (I don't know what to look for).

Comment: Hi Tomer, I'm guessing the link is dead in part because there is a new Scala reflection API being released with scala 2.10.  The [second milestone is already available](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/12550) and it has a preliminary reflection API.  You might want to [look at the scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/milestone/index.html#scala.reflect.package).

Comment: Here is [an updated link](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/teaching/projects/archive/coppel_report.pdf), but you are probably better off looking into reflection in 2.10.  There are a few [stackoverflow posts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477248/what-reflection-capabilities-can-we-expect-from-scala-2-10) on the matter and some [blog posts](http://alots.wordpress.com/2012/03/06/getting-into-the-new-scalas-2-10-reflection-api/).

Comment: This is the [most helpful information](http://ochsenreither.posterous.com/whats-new-in-210) I've seen about 2.10.