# Scala - Passing Trait type as method parameter

Tags: scala

In java,  we can have a method that takes Class as a parameter, for example :

```
void someMethod(Class className)
{
   System.out.println(className);
}
```

similarly, instead of Class, is there a way in scala to take Trait as a parameter ?

Answer (score 4):

If you could do that, how would you use it?

A Scala trait is compiled into an interface and a corresponding class. You can pass the interface into a method (since interfaces are a kind of Class):

```
scala> trait Foo
scala> val c: Class = classOf[Foo]
a: Class[Foo] = interface Foo

scala> def someMethod(c: Class[_]) = c.getName
scala> someMethod(a)
res1: String = Foo
```

The class part is compiled into a hidden `Foo$class` classfile. However, you can pass a Class that *implements* your Trait into a method. I'm not aware of a way to pass a Trait directly, due to the split into the underlying Java class and interface.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2558317/699224) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1836124/699224)